# Continuously data transfer with sockets

Tags: c#, asyncsocket

I've created a basic C# application that is receiving and sending data with sockets. Currently I'm able to send data from my client to my server and I can receive response.
My problem is: As a client I don't know how to check if the server has send me anything new. Normally I send something as client and receive response there is no problem but sometimes server has to send me some information.
This is my current code sample, I'll update this post if I change the code

My server side code is like this:

```
 public class StateObject
        {
            // Client  socket.  
            public Socket workSocket = null;
            // Size of receive buffer.  
            public const int BufferSize = 1024;
            // Receive buffer.  
            public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
            // Received data string.  
            public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


        }

        public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        public void StartListening()
        {
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 10101);

            Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            try
            {
                listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
                listener.Listen(10);

                while (true)
                {
                    allDone.Reset();
                    listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);
                    allDone.WaitOne();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }


        public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            allDone.Set();

            Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = handler;
            ClientList.Add(handler);

            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);

        }

        public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            string content = string.Empty;
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = state.workSocket;

            int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
                content = state.sb.ToString();
                if (content.IndexOf("_|_!#*#_") > -1)
                {
                    HandleIncomingMessage(handler, content.Substring(0, content.Length - 8));
                }
                else
                {
                    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
                }
            }
        }

        private void HandleIncomingMessage(Socket handler, string data)
        {
            CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
            Response response = new Response();


            byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

            listView1.Items.Add(data);
            response = ParserToSocket(data);

            if (response == null)
            {
                response = new Response();
                response.Status = "false";
                response.Message = "Json not valid" + data;
            }
            if (response.Status == null)
                response.Status = "false";
            if (response.Message == null)
                response.Message = "Error while creating response message";

            byte[] ByteArrayToSend = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response) + "_|_!#*#_");


            handler.BeginSend(ByteArrayToSend, 0, ByteArrayToSend.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);

        }

        private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);

                Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
                StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

and this is code for my client side :

```
 public class StateObject
        {
            public Socket workSocket = null;
            public const int BufferSize = 512;
            public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
            public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        }

    private string response = string.Empty;
    public Socket ConnectedSocket;

    IPHostEntry ipHostInfo;
    IPAddress ipAddress;
    IPEndPoint remoteEP;

    private string StartClient()
    {
        try
        {
            ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1");
            ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 10101);
            ConnectedSocket = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            ConnectedSocket.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), ConnectedSocket);
            return "";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CLIENT ERROR : \n" + e.ToString());
            return "";
        }
    }
    private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            client.EndConnect(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected to server.");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }


    public string SendMessageToServer(string text)
    {
        StartClient();
        response = string.Empty;
        text += "_|_!#*#_";
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

        ConnectedSocket.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), ConnectedSocket);
        while(response.IndexOf("_|_!#*#_") == -1)
        {

        }
        response = response.Replace("_|_!#*#_", "");
        return response;
    }

    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);

            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = client;
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                response = state.sb.ToString();

                if (response.IndexOf("_|_!#*#_") != -1)
                {
                    state.sb.Clear();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                if (state.sb.Length > 1)
                {
                    response = state.sb.ToString();
                }
                client.EndReceive(ar);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: You seem to setup a connection for each message from client to server. Is there a reason for that? Usually, you'd setup one (long lived) TCP connection and communicate back and forth as you like.

Comment: Sidenote: I am sure people will also suggest to use async/await (TPL) instead of the legacy Begin/End-Async pattern.

Comment: No there is no reason, I'm still new on programming so I try to learn. I tried listing the socket's to send them data for later but even if I have achieve this in code above I don't know how to retrieve the data on client side

Comment: You need to set up a listener that will work independently from your main thread. Maybe look for a tutorial on "multithreaded or concurrent tcp client/server".

Comment: Okay but can I also do this with the same socket that I might send data? Because I cannot open ports on client sides as I want

Comment: Sockets are bidirectional. You can send and receive on one socket at the same time. But in order to listen concurrently, you either need to ReadAsync and await or block a separate thread on a synchronous Read.

Comment: Okay then my goal should be (as client) sending the data and speaking with server but also I have to open a sync thread that will read the incoming message right?